# How can emit an EventEmitter from an NgbModal in Angular12?

Tags: angular

I have been wrestling with making a bootstrap modal reusable component but it's getting more complex than it should be. I finally have the modal component rendering as a reusable component props-wise but I can't emit an event for some reason. I tried to do a Stack Blitz and that was a failure too because of all the moving parts. So I hope this is enough. Sorry. I'll try to explain as much as I can.

MODAL.COMPONENT.TS

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'modal-content',
  template: `
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h4>   
      <button 
        type="button" 
        class="close" 
        (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span>&times;</span>
      </button> 
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      {{content}}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button 
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary"
        (click)="activeModal.close()">
        {{ secondaryButtonText }}
      </button>
      <button 
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-danger"
        (click)="remove()">
        {{ primaryButtonText }}
      </button>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ModalContent {
  @Input() title: string
  @Input() content: string
  @Input() primaryButtonText: string
  @Input() secondaryButtonText: string
  
  @Output() clickEvnt = new EventEmitter()

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}

  remove() {
    console.log("Hello"); //SO FAR THIS IS THE ONLY THING THAT SHOWS IN THE CONSOLE. WHICH MEANS IT'S NOT EMITTING. IT'S FIRING LOCALLY
    
    this.clickEvnt.emit() // THIS IS THE EVENT THAT I AM EMITTING
  }
} 


@Component({
  selector: 'confirmation-modal',
  templateUrl: './confirmation-modal.component.html'
})

export class ConfirmationModalComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalContent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.title = 'Delete';
    modalRef.componentInstance.content = 'Are you sure you want to delete this task?';
    modalRef.componentInstance.primaryButtonText="Yes";
    modalRef.componentInstance.secondaryButtonText="No";    
  }

}
```

MODAL.COMPONENT.HTML

```
// Simple enough. Just a button that open the modal. The modal component (above) includes the modal itself as well as the functionality within it
<button (click)="open()" class="text-danger"></button>
```

RECEIVING.COMPONENT.HTML

```
// The modal is received and the event that was emitted should be caught here (???) right? And in turn, it fires the onDelete() which at the moment all it has is a console log to test it
<confirmation-modal (clickEvnt)="onDelete(task)"></confirmation-modal>
```

What am I missing? :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post you Stack Blitz?

Comment: I think, there where you set your modal inputs, you can subscribe to the even emitter: modalRef.componentInstance. clickEvnt.subscribe( event => doSomething(event))

Comment: @Den I tried and I failed at even running it. SO many moving parts and dependencies. It's almost like I need to make a question to help me with StackBlitz so I can ask the actual question after that lol It took me nearly 4 hours to try to put on together. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-usa99k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change the stackblitz and now working.

How say @MikeOne you need to subscrive to the event emitter:

```
@Output() clickEvnt = new EventEmitter();

open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.title = 'Delete';
    modalRef.componentInstance.content =
      'Are you sure you want to delete this task?';
    modalRef.componentInstance.primaryButtonText = 'Yes';
    modalRef.componentInstance.secondaryButtonText = 'No';

    modalRef.componentInstance. clickEvnt.subscribe( event => this.clickEvnt.emit());
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't get the stack blitz to work either. This solution gave me an error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')`

Comment: Not to mention, I can see the error firing when the modal comes on. So it's rendering the modal useless because if it did work, It would have removed the item before I said yes to the modal

Comment: this is my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-usa99k-nc8xwr?file=src/app/components/modal/modal-component.ts

Comment: Thank you for making the stackblitz work. I'm still having the problem with the emit. As you can see it is logging "Hi!" to the console. Thats' before the emit. If it was emitting, it would have logged "deleted" from the home component

Comment: if you click yes, in console appare hi! and Delete! what is the problem? i don't understand your problem

Comment: No it doesn't my friend. Unless there is an update you haven't saved. The Delete message never logs

Comment: Now it's showing. Let me check against my code.

Comment: In your sub component there must be no logic ... you have to pass what you need and execute it from the father ... otherwise you can execute the call and at the end execute the emit ...